# Why do electrodes have to touch initially in order to establish an arc?

Tags: electricity, electric-circuits

In order to establish an arc in a low voltage, high current suruation such as welding, why do the wires or electrodes need to touch, then pull away to establish an arc?

Why would this arc not be established when the electrodes were brought close to one another initially?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Electric (arc) welding is performed at relatively low voltage (often less than 10 volts) and high current (150 to 250 amps). This means the electrode needs to brought very close indeed to the workpiece, in order to trigger breakdown and start the arc. In practice, the arc is initially "struck" by physically tapping or swiping the workpiece with the tip of the electrode in the vicinity of the desired weld, which will throw sparks- and one of them will very quickly develop into a fully-formed arc. Then the welding process begins.

Answer (score 2):

They don't technically have to touch.  They just have to get close enough for the field to exceed the breakdown limit of air (around 3kV/mm).

So if you're doing something at 750V, you just need around...

$$d = \frac{V}{E_{break}} = \frac{750\text{V}}{3\text{kV/mm}} = 0.25\text{mm}$$

Once the wires are closer than this, an arc will tend to form.  In practice, that distance is so close that you may not notice if it starts before contact.

Comment: Thank you very much. Once the arc is formed and the electrodes slightly separate, I assume that the arc is maintained as the air between the electrodes is now essentially a conductor?

Comment: That's correct.  The higher conductivity allows more energy to be delivered, replenishing the ionization.

Comment: that is correct.